# How to interpret these smartctl results? Possible solutions?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl, badblocks, sata

Do I need to dump my SATA hard disk, based on the following `smartctl` results?

I was frequently getting filesystem errors during boot time and even `fsck` failed to repair it last time. Then I used a live USB (Fedora) and checked it with the Disks utility; it showed 2500+ bad sectors.

I searched the Internet for repair procedures and found out that "full formatting with zero-filling" may resolve bad sectors. I did it, it took 12+ hours on my SATA hard disk. The bad sectors didn't vanished, but reduced to 776 (as shown by the Disk utility).

Then, I decided to do a SMART test, using `smartctl` to get detailed results. Short SMART test passed, but not the extended one (see log structure below). The results were difficult to interpret for possible repair so I decided to bring the issue here.

Should I use the hard disk now?

Please check the detailed results below and suggest.

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo smartctl -a -d ata /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Mobile HDD
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Serial Number:    ZDE6YPLW
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0a5ef85fb
Firmware Version: LCM2
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri May 22 09:37:52 2020 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 163) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   080   037   034    Pre-fail  Always       -       190487919
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2272
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   095   095   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       784
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   080   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       107066354
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5196 (144 134 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1855
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       33763
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       107375951904
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   061   050   040    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 26/45)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       167
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       67875
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   039   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (0 10 0 0 0)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       784
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   078   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x000f   095   095   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4839 (0 13 0)
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 36087 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 36087 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5164 hours (215 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:19.673  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:18.472  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:02:18.378  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:02:18.351  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:02:18.349  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 36086 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5164 hours (215 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 10 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:15.945  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:15.945  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:15.945  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:15.944  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:15.944  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 36085 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5164 hours (215 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 38 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:02.115  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 f0 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:02.114  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:02.114  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:02.114  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:02:02.113  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 36084 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5164 hours (215 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.737  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.736  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:01:53.707  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 00 38 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.688  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.678  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 36083 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5164 hours (215 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.049  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.049  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.049  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.049  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:53.049  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5196         318795064
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5194         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      5194         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5194         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5164         808789760
# 6  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5164         808789760
# 7  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5158         1348112200
# 8  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5158         1348112200
# 9  Short offline       Completed: read failure       80%      5143         1348112200
#10  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5139         344992248
#11  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      5139         344992248
#12  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      5139         344992248

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I can't find any official specifications from this manufacturer (for your HDD model). But, based on the [known SMART attributes as listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes), I'd conclude the drive is unreliable and you should just return/replace it. See, in particular, attributes 196, 197 and, especially, 198 from the aforementioned list: they likely indicate some disk surface or mechanical defects.

Answer (score 3):

To interpret the SMART attributes, you have to know they are normalized to 100, and lower is worse.

You have a significant raw read error rate, and also a significant seek error rate, and on top of that quite a few sectors have already been relocated. The other attributes indicate only a bit of wear, but the first two mentioned attributes means that you harddisk can no longer properly read the bitstream of data on the harddisk. It may be a mechanical error that causes bad alignment, or some electronic error in the read or write circuitry, or some defect on the surface, or something else.

If this was my harddisk, I'd make a backup right now, and throw it out - this harddisk will never reliably store any data anymore. If you bought it "as new", give it back and complain that the SMART values clearly show it is not new.

Comment: my laptop's under warranty, do they accept these results for replacement or repair

Comment: also I want to know if this is solely hard disk's fault, or laptop has to do something with it, as,  if i get new one, i would be sure that it won't get ruined

Comment: I have no idea; ask your dealer. Depending on what country you are in, and the company you bought it from, they may or may not try to make things difficult for you; but a warranty *should* cover this case.

Comment: I also have no idea if your laptop has something to do with, as I don't know what caused the problems of your harddisk. Though I don't see how it could be the laptop's fault; I think we can rule out thermal problems.