# What are these three numbers in parenthesis next to "Power_On_Hours" in `smartctl -a` output?

Tags: ssd, smartctl

Sometimes the output of the `smartctl -a` command shows three numbers separated by spaces in parenthesis after the value of Power_On_Hours. This can be seen in multiple previously asked questions here:

1. [Deciphering smartctl results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708275/deciphering-smartctl-results)

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
...
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       55 (236 20 0)
```

2. [How to interpret these smartctl results? Possible solutions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588251/how-to-interpret-these-smartctl-results-possible-solutions)

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
...
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5196 (144 134 0)
```

3. [Meaning of Smartctl output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752110/meaning-of-smartctl-output)

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
...
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2985 (94 211 0)
```

What do these three numbers mean? I can't seem to find the answer anywhere on the Internet.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: `man smartctl`, `/raw`